# DDD Validator Specification with dependency on repository

Tags: domain-driven-design, dependency-injection, validation

I have read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818898/where-to-put-global-rules-validation-in-ddd and I have create my validator.

But now I need to create a validator that must check the order entity.

This is the problem: When I create or edit an entity "Car", I need to check 2 conditions:

I can't have the property Color with value "Red" if there are 10 or more entity Car with the Color = "Red".
I can't have the property Color with value "Red" if the entity "Warehouse" haven't the entry with item code "FF0000"
For this check i need to use my ICarRepository for count the item with property Red, and the IWarehouseRepostiory for check if there are an item with code "FF0000".

```
public class CarValidator : IValidator<Car>
{
    public CarValidator(ICarRepository carRepository, IWahrehouseRepository wahrehouseRepository)
{
.....
}

    private readonly IList<ISpecification<Car>> Rules =
        new List<ISpecification<Car>>
            {
                new AvaiableRedColorSpecification(carRepository, wahrehouseRepository),
            };

    public bool IsValid(Car entity)
    {
        return BrokenRules(entity).Count() > 0;
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> BrokenRules(Car entity)
    {
        return Rules.Where(rule => !rule.IsSatisfiedBy(entity))
                    .Select(rule => GetMessageForBrokenRule(rule));
    }
}

public class AvaiableRedColorSpecification : ISpecification<Car>
{
    public bool IsSatisfiedBy(ICarRepository carRepository, IWahrehouseRepository wahrehouseRepository)
    {
        return carRepository.CountRedColor() < 10 &&
                wahrehouseRepository.HaveItemCode("FF0000");

    }
}
```

What is the best way to inject the my dependency, because in this way I need to inject the repository inside the Car entity for Add/Edit, I think it's not a good idea inject the repository inside my entity

**[EDIT IMPLEMENTATION AFTER READ AL RESPONSE]**

I have decide to use Validation Pattern, so I have create a

```
interface IRuleSpecification<T>
{
    Task<ValidatorResult> IsSatisfiedAsync(T subject);
}
interface IValidator<T, TResult>
{
    Task ExecuteCheckAsync(T entity, TResult validateObject);
    bool IsValid { get; }
    IEnumerable<ValidatorResult> BrokenRules { get; }
    TResult ValidateObject { get; }
}

public static async Task<IValidator<CarDto, CarEntity>> FactoryCreator(CarDto dto, IEnumerable<IRuleSpecification<CarDto>> rules)
{ ... }
```

In this everytime I try to create entity car, I must pass the IRuleSpecification in the class that have a responsability to call factory (in my case use the CQRS I call CarCreatorCommand).

CarCreatorCommand recive the list of IRuleSpecification by dependy injection.

The implementation class of IRuleSpecification have injected the IRepository for receve the list of color avaiable. In this way the validator have the depence by IReposiory.

Comment: Am I missing something here? Where in your code are you inject the repository inside the Car entity?

Comment: You probably have a bug in `IsValid` too, since you return true if there are broken rules. If it breaks the rules, it ain't valid.

Comment: yes sorry, this code is only an example for try to know the correct way for check the validity in my entity

Answer (score 1):

When you inject repositories or other dependencies into the domain, the domain becomes less pure. Impure domain models are harder to test and reason about. Therefore pure domain models are preferred.

So, how would it be possible to satisfy the two conditions below, without injecting a repository?

> I can't have the property Color with value "Red" if there are 10 or more entity Car with the Color = "Red".

> I can't have the property Color with value "Red" if the entity "Warehouse" haven't the entry with item code "FF0000".

The `Car` entity could have a method or constructor that takes the required information as arguments, instead of fetching it from a repository. For example:

```
public static Car Create(Model model, Engine engine, Color desiredColor, IReadOnlyList<ColorCount> usedColors, IReadOnlyList<Color> availableColors)
{
   // do validation on usedColors and availableColors
   return new Car(model, engine, desiredColor);
}
```

Before calling this method from an application service, you fetch the information from the repository. The usedColors collection contains the number of times each color is used and the availableColors collection contains all the colors in the warehouse.

This way, all decisions can be made inside the domain, without any out-of-process dependencies.

Comment: I like this solution, only one question there is the possibility to call directly Car(model, engine, desiredColor) and bypass the check in this way. There are some pattern o best practice for deny the access do create directly Car() and use everytime the services Create ?

Comment: Sure, make the constructor private and place the Create factory method inside the Car class. From outside, you call `Car.Create(...)` which will return a new instance of a Car.

Comment: It's completely valid to pass domain services as arguments to methods of domain entities, in order for the domain entity to invoke an appropriate method. The domain models shouldn't have a member variable of such type (making the model's construction quite difficult), but passing them in a transitive manner is fine.

Comment: @Andy Passing **domain services** to an entity is fine. It's no neccesary in this case, but there are certainly situations where there's no logical entity to encapsulate business logic, so a domain service can be used. I'm not sure why that's relevant to this answer tbh.

Comment: Based on the initial paragraph, are you then also suggesting that inverted dependencies are impure? Because that's quite the can of worms to open. I also suspect that @Andy's comment is related to that observation (Andy: feel free to correct me). As you yourself say, passing domain services is fine, so then an inverted dependency is as valid to use as a domain service, no?

Comment: @Andy but Domain Layer can reference DomainService Layer? Becase i think (and in my solution is) the DomanService has a reference to Domain.

Comment: @Flater correct, inverted dependencies are also impure. The impurity comes from the fact that an external, out-of-process dependency (like a database) is required to make the decision **inside** the domain. In my proposed solution, the database is still needed to satisfy the use-case as a whole, but not inside the domain model. Note that **domain services** are part of the domain, they encapsulate business logic, just like entities or value objects. A repository is not a domain service.

Comment: @RikD: Your definition of "inside" is a very unusual one. When injecting an inverted dependency, the dependency's logic isn't being executed "in" the object it gets injected into. The dependency is still a separate object with its own separate responsibilities. If that is your definition of "inside", then you effectively argue that the entire dependency graph (db context, domain logic, ...) is all executed "inside" the object which sits at the top of that graph (e.g. the api controller). If correct, that would effectively invalidate the entire concept of layer separation in a dependency graph.

Comment: @RikD _"A repository is not a domain service."_ When dealing with an inverted dependency, the repository's _interface_ (not class!) is part of the domain (or the contracts which are included in the domain - same difference for this situation). The specific implementation (i.e. repository class, which implements said interface) is not part of the domain, but that is besides the point since the domain doesn't reference nor handle the repository class at any point.

Comment: @Flater there's code that lives inside the domain model and code that lives outside it. I'm suggesting that code that accesses the database (directly or inverted) should live outside the domain code. In the DDD community there's a saying **make the implicit explicit** and by passing a list of colors instead of an interface to a database, you do just that.

Comment: @RikD: You seem to misunderstand inverted dependencies. **The repository class does not live in the domain**. Only the repository _interface_ lives in the domain (or a separate contracts class referenced by the domain). The repository class lives in the persistence layer, which depends on the domain (or that separate contracts class which contains the repository interface).

Comment: Also think of writing a unit test for the Create method. Instead of mocking the repository, you create a list of colors.

Comment: @Flater I understand the concept of inverted dependencies and I argue that there are ways to keep both the interface and implementation of a database out of the domain model to keep it pure.

Comment: @Flater this is the approach I meant by passing references to services to domain models, which I consider to be a valid approach to not make models beans while keeping the business rules within them: https://pastebin.com/bidrizfx Know that this is a very quick mockup and the actual code would likely include value objects representing Email and Password, therefore not needing to pass the `PasswordHashService` to the registration method, instead it would accept a `Password password` instance.

Comment: @RikD: I didn't claim that you can't have both of them outside of the domain. But you're arguing that inverted dependencies are also impure because "inverted dependecies execute database logic in the domain", which is simply not true. There's a difference between "my solution is good" (which I agree with) and "doing the opposite of my solution is bad/worse" (which I disagree with, and is what your first paragraph implies and on closer inspection seems based on a misunderstanding of what inverted dependencies are)

Comment: @Andy: Yeah that's pretty much what I meant, the interface is known in the domain but the concrete class is not (I'm not seeing your concrete class but I infer that you'd place that class outside of the domain).

Comment: @Flater I didn't (mean to) say *"inverted dependecies execute database logic in the domain"*. I meant that in order for the domain code to make a decision, a call has to be made to an out-of-process dependency.

Comment: @Andy The registerNew method could take a `bool emailIsUnique` and a `string hashedPassword` so it doesn't have to depend on (implementations of) those interfaces. What benefit do these two additional dependencies give exactly?

Comment: The benefit is that the business rule is contained within the object itself and it's no longer as easy to simply pass a `false` to the method as an argument, perhaps by mistake. You would need to provide a specialised `UserRegistrationService` implementation in order to pass a `false` value to it, and there's very low likelihood you would accidentally type out an entire implementation (and that it would pass the code review, too). Separate unit tests are provided for the `UserRegistrationService` and the user creation process (in which the service's implementation may be mocked).

Comment: @Andy Good point. In a real world scenario I wouldn't put primitive types on the Create method, but Value Objects or perhaps an enum, so it wouldn't be so easy to mistakenly pass an incorrect argument by mistake.

Comment: @RikD The only thing I dislike about resolving & providing the data needed by a given implementation of a conceptual rule such as `AvailableColorRule` is that you can't make the `AvailableColorRule` concept a first-class citizen of your domain, where there could be various implementations of such rule. You are forced to provide the dependencies of a given concrete "AvailableColorRule" implementation. I'm not sure there's a good solution for this while preserving purity.

Comment: I guess you could have a factory for the rules which resolves the dependencies of a given rule before constructing it with the context it needs to evaluate, allowing the rules themselves to stay pure. Something like `availableColorRule = AvailableColorRule.default(); new Car(..., availableColorRule )`. You can't create the `Car` without checking the rule and the rule dependencies can evolve independently of the `Car`. The only thing is that we'd need a way to express a given rule was O.K to use in a given context.

Comment: @Flater (and other all) thanks for your comments, I have use the implementation explained in the EDIT part of my post. I have inject the repository dependency in the class that implement the IRuleSpecification

Answer (score 1):

There is something missing here. What are the actual rules?

The obvious answer is, of course, that you *can* create a `Car` of any `Color`. You just can't *do* anything with it! What are you trying to do with your `Car`? That is, what is the *behavior* of this system?

Are we trying to `Assemble` them? Then what? `Store` them?

```csharp
class CarFactory 
{ 
    public CarFactory(List<Model> models, List<Engine> engines, List<Color> colors)
     
    public Car Assemble(CarSpec spec)
    {
        //validate specification against available components
    }
}

// VO
class CarSpec
{
    public readonly Model model

    public readonly Engine engine

    public readonly Color color
}

class CarWarehouse
{
    public CarWarehouse(List<Car> cars)

    // alternatively
    public CarWarehouse(Dictionary<Color, int> numberOfEachColor)

    public InventoryTicket Store(Car car)
    {
        //validate the Car's current color against inventory
    }
}
```

Now we can surmise a use-case like:

```csharp
// Manufacture Car Handler

var spec = new CarSpec(cmd.Model, cmd.Engine, cmd.Color)

var car = factory.Assemble(spec) // may throw

var ticket = warehouse.Store(car) // may throw

repo.Save(car, ticket)
```

Importantly, the above isn't focused on the data, but rather, the *behavior* of our system. We are not worrying about generic "specifications" or "rules" or checking if anything "is valid". We are just embedding our domain logic.. well... directly into the domain! It's simpler this way. Each invariant is being enforced in precisely the same context in which it applies. That is, *within the unit of behavior* in which it is relevant.

We don't care about the components of a `Car` until we want to *do* something with that `Car`. That's how business *processes* work: "We can't *manufacture* (assemble and store) a `Car` if it doesn't meet some criteria." The fundamental perspective that DDD seeks to provide (really OOP) is that behavior needs to be placed *with* data, not *around* data.

**Don't validate the data, validate the process.**

In this way `Validator<Car>` really represents the antithesis of DDD. We are choosing to focus on the data (`Car`) instead of the behavior. We aren't *just* validating a `Car`, we are validating a `Car` within some context. What is that context? I don't see those words *in* your domain. Something is missing...

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the domain has the concept of a "Rule".  These rules transcend the Car entity, but define what a valid warehouse is.

Imagine the requirements would scale up, and a the solution should support several warehouses.  In that case each warehouse should support a different set of rules (depending on warehouse size, cultural issues, ...).

So, validation of these Rules is tied to the warehouse's `addCar` function.  Cars should not bother about other cars.  Entities should not bother about the aggregates they're in.

The problem you're facing is a direct consequence of this design flaw.

I can imagine the use case should limit the number of available colors for a car in a warehouse; if that's the case, the Rules should probably be an accessible property of the warehouse: `wareHouse.availableCarColors`.

Comment: But in case of the rule is the name of car is unique (without using the unique key on database) the solution is the same? because this rule is apply with only the Car Domain or in this case we can adopter another solution?

Comment: What xtofl is basically saying is that Car shouldn’t be the aggregate root, but Warehouse. Instead of Car.Create something like Warehouse.CreateCar(...). Because Warehouse knows which cars are inside, you can validate the new cars color against the colors of the other cars in the warehouse. This approach can definitely work, but in general we should favor small aggregates. This could potentially load a tremendous amount of data.

Comment: @RikD exactly.  If the warehouse has a rule about 'used colors', it should probably store (and maintain) the used colors explicitly (or have a DB stored procedure for it, or ...).  Thanks for pointing me to the right wording.